# SharePoint Branding and Parallax Scrolling

Tags: branding, 2013, design

Has anyone been able to design SharePoint UI using Parallax scrolling? Similar to the following site http://www.milwaukeepolicenews.com/#menu=home-page (I am not affiliated with this site in anyway)

Nothing is impossible; but, I would like to know how difficult is it to design such an interface. Is there any documentation about this kind of design with SharePoint?

When we started to hear about SP 2013 a year ago, there was this very nice SP Metro style UI. I hope a similar UI come to fruition. This is not parallax scrolling, but it's just looks too nice :)

[image]

Comment: Will you use it just on an external web site, just for publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First... are you positive that it will give your users an enhanced interaction with your site or are you doing it because it's cool? If you're doing it because you think it's neat, I'd definitely look into this article [How The Web Design Trend of Parallax Scrolling Has Faded](http://www.designyourway.net/drb/how-the-web-design-trend-of-parallax-scrolling-has-faded/).

Here are two tutorials on how to make that effect happen.
[Simple Parallax Scrolling Technique](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/)
[How to Smartly Use Parallax Scrolling for Your Website](http://www.webdesign.org/tips-on-how-to-smartly-use-parallax-scrolling-for-your-website.22306.html)

Beware, it can cause your site to load much slower and unless you're super good with the technique then it most likely won't work on a mobile device. If after all that consideration it still makes sense, then have at it and let us know how it goes!